# return object of the method throws exception does not handle, how to fix it?

Tags: java, exception

I have made an immutable class that implements the responsibilities about Matrix operations
its constructor throws an exception in confronting with invalid input

```
    public Class Matrix{
      public Matrix(int[][] matrix) throws Exception {
        if (!isValid(matrix))
          throw new Exception("Bad Matrix");
        sth();
        sth();
        sth();
      }


      public Matrix transpose() {
        int[][] transposeMatrix = new int[column][row];
        sth();
        sth();
        sth();

        try {
            return new Matrix(transposeMatrix);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
```

in transpose method, a new instance of the Matrix class wants to be instantiated ,it's obvious that this method is responsible to handle the exception and this is the problem now I don't know how to return an instance of Matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are throwing `Exception` in the constructor.  Throwing and / or declaring `Exception` is almost always *a really bad idea*.

In this case, it is better to throw a *specific* unchecked exception.  Either declare your own exception class, or throw an existing one.  `IllegalArgumentException` would be a good choice.

Since `IllegalArgumentException` is unchecked, you won't need to declare it in your `Matrix` constructor's signature, and you won't need to "catch or declare" it everywhere you use the constructor.

---

As to how you should return a `Matrix` if you can't construct it.  There are two straightforward<sup>1</sup> answers:

1. Don't catch the exception.  Let it propagate to the caller ... which provided the invalid input in the first place.
2. Return a `null`.  Note this *must* be done in the code that calls the constructor, since a constructor **cannot** return `null`.

**HOWEVER**, returning `null` leads to other problems:

- If the caller of (say) `transpose` doesn't check the result of the call, and act appropriately, this is liable to lead to NullPointerException down the track.
- If the call *does* check, there is nothing explaining *why* the result is `null`.  Indeed, any explanation that you might have included in the exception message will have been discarded (or dumped into the log, etc as a stacktrace) so that there is nothing to tell the end user ... about their bad input.

---

<sup>1 - There is a third approach too.  Implement a way to represent an *invalid* matrix as a `Matrix` instance.  For example you *could* declare a subclass of `Matrix` and call it `InvalidMatrix`.  Some of the methods of this subclass would raise exceptions; e.g. "you cannot transpose an invalid matrix".  This would also entail using a factory method, since the `new` operation cannot create instances of different classes depending on the arguments.

It could be argued that this violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) since an `InvalidMatrix` cannot be used as a real matrix.  But it could also be argued that it *doesn't* violate LSP, since any Java method or constructor can *implicitly* throw an unchecked exception. Either way, it is a *pragmatic* solution.

Note that there examples of this kind of thing in the standard Java SE class library.  For instance the  `unmodifiableList` method in `Collections` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))) creates a `List` instance that throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` if you try to modify it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are some statements you can use in the catch block, 1st is throwing Runtime Exception, 2nd is returning empty matrix and 3rd is returning null;

1. `throw new RuntimeException();`
2. `return new Matrix(new int[0][0]);`
3. `return null;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was looking for a refactoring based solution, which was achieved in the post marked as green solution